# Is it possible to perform fql queries via the javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm playing with a sample app which is meant to show me a filtered version of my facebook stream.  I'd like to use the javascript sdk for this, to avoid any extra traffic to my server. Is this possible?

So far I've been experimenting with the likes of:

```
 FB.api('/fql', {q:query}, function(response) {});
```

which doesn't seem to be implemented. I'd rather not use the legacy REST api, since, well, it's legacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 FB.api('fql', { q: 'query here' }, function (response)
{
 //Logic here
};
```

Pretty much, you just need to remove the slash in front of the 'fql'.